# Does EF track related models, and set their foreign keys when needed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have two EF models/classes that have relation between them: **Member** and **MembershipSeason**. One **Member** can have several **MembershipSeasons**. One **MembershipSeason** model has a foreign key reference (**MemberID**) to **Member** model in db.

**Member.cs**

```
public class Member
{
        public int MemberID { get; set; }

        //some properties left out
        public virtual ICollection<MembershipSeason> MembershipSeasons { get; set; }
 }
```

**MembershipSeason.cs**

```
public class MembershipSeason
{
        [Key]
        public int MembershipSeasonID { get; set; }

        //some properties left out
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

I experimented to post those two models to the same **Create** method together in the same time. I discovered that EF tracks those two models and saves them into db as new models. It also links those two models by setting **MemberID** of the new **Member** model as foreign key to the new **MembershipSeason** model in db. I guess this is planned behaviour? – I mean the fact EF sets foreign key to the related models automatically seems to be expected behaviour – how things should work. Therefore I guess I don’t need to save **Member** model first, obtain it’s **MemberID** and use it for **MembershipSeason** and save it separately in the **Create** method? (because EF does the work for you)

```
 db.Members.Add(member);

 db.MembershipSeasons.Add(membershipSeason);

 await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The above and the below **Create** method works in the way that no **MemberID** property is needed to be set directly to **MembershipSeason** model, because EF does it automatically.

**MemberController.cs**

```
public class MemberController : Controller
{
        private MembersContext db = new MembersContext();

        //some code left out

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "MemberNumber,FirstName,LastName")] Member member,
            [Bind(Include = "HasPaidMembership,SeasonId")] MembershipSeason membershipSeason)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Members.Add(member);

                    db.MembershipSeasons.Add(membershipSeason);

                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
            }
            return View(member);
        }
    }
```

I am quite new with EF and ASP.NET MVC, so I am trying to figure these things out. Any help appreciated – thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It also links those two models by setting MemberID of the new Member model as foreign key to the new MembershipSeason model in db. I guess this is planned behaviour?

**TL;DR: *Yes***

Yes, it has to be the required behavior.  Lets start with reads:

```
public class Organization
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
  public Organization Organization { get; set; }
}

public Employee GetEmployeeWithOrganization(guid id)
{
  var result = _context.Employees
    .Include(e => e.Organization)
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id = id);
}
```

Basically when you ask EF to include the navigation property you'd get an object graph kinda like:

```
Employee
- Id : <guid1>
- OrganizationId : <guid2>
- Organization : object
  - Id : <guid2>
```

It would be common sense to assume that because [EF should keep track of entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613924(v=vs.113).aspx) because what happens if you do this:

```
var employee = GetEmployeeWithOrganization(<guid1>)

var org = new Organization { id = guid.NewGuid() }; //<guid3>

employee.Organization = org;

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Which one of these is a valid object:

A:

```
Employee
- Id : <guid1>
- OrganizationId : <guid2>  // <-- difference
- Organization : object
  - Id : <guid3>
```

B:

```
Employee
- Id : <guid1>
- OrganizationId : <guid3>  // <-- difference
- Organization : object
  - Id : <guid3>
```

A isn't valid, because you can't rely on the values and programming against that object would not only be a completely nightmare, but at the database level doesn't make sense.  B is valid, it is data you can rely on.

This also means you can precache items and EF will write them up automagically.  Consider:

```
var org = GetOrganization(<guid3>);

var emp = GetEmployee(<guid1>);

Assert.That(emp.Organization, Is.Not.Null);  // passes
```

This happens because EF is tracking org and because EF is configured with org as a FK to employee.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer and for the useful MSDN link on Entity Framework Self-Tracking Entities. Now I can continue using EF, without worrying that any unexpected behavior might show up in the process :-)